# Hyper V: Network Adapter Drivers

Tags: networking, windows-xp, hyper-v

It seems I need to use legacy adapter drivers to get network connections with older version of windows and fedora (fedora 14 and windows xp), but with the newer versions I can use regular network adapters. Is there a way I can install the correct drivers needed for the regular network adapters to connect on the older guest OS's or are the drivers needed to connect incompatible windows xp and fedora 14?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hyper-V has two kinds of NICs:  emulated and synthetic.  *Emulated* corresponds to what your refer to as 'legacy'.  *Synthetic* corresponds to what you call a 'regular network adapter'.

To operate a synthetic NIC, the guest OS needs extra drivers.  These are called *Integration Services*

AFAIK, Hyper-V ships with drivers for WindowsXP.  They come in the form of an ISO that you can add to attach to the VM's DVD drive.  Under the Hyper-V manager, connect to the VM (select the VM, then use Action -> Connect...), and in the window that pops use Action -> Insert Integration Services Setup Disk.  You install the drivers from inside the Guest O/S.

For Linux OS's, you should download [*Linux Integration Services 3.4*](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34603), which is the latest at the time of writing.  Unfortunately, only CentOS and RHEL are explicitly supported.  You can try installing the RPMs that come with Linux Integration Services, but its unclear whether they will work properly.

Good luck!

**Update:**

Hyper-V drivers have been added to the linux kernel.  I posted details on how to determine if they are available with your distro [on my blog](http://dlafferty.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/installing-hyper-v-pv-drivers-for-linux.html).